# Laptop switches off during the installation process

Tags: installation, livedvd

I am installing Ubuntu 12.10 on an acer 5315 laptop. I have burned an image of the ISO on a DVD and when the disk boots everything looks like it is going according to plan. I choose the option to replace my windows OS and delete all data and files and the install begins. I pass the various screens while the files are being copied but then at some stage during the copying process my laptop just switches itself off with no warning. I have tried 3 times now and it always switches off at completely different times during the installation. Any ideas?  the DVD is brand new and seems perfect.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the dvd for errors during burning (ie. does the checksum check out)? Any reason for using the dvd and not the CD? If not ... please try with an official live CD.

Answer (score 0):

Get the .iso image ONLY from www.ubuntu.com/download/ Use a torrent [available at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads ] if you're using a slow connection. Burn onto a new DVD at a slow speed using a system different fro the previous one.

If it still fails, you can try installing on your HDD using another machine. For eg, I failed many ties while installing FreeBSD on my laptop (and on a friend's laptop of same make & model), but it went smooth on both HDDs when I used them in my Desktop!

Good luck!